# hashCode and equals for Collections.unmodifiableCollection()

Tags: java, collections, unmodifiable

The `Collections` class has a number of static helper methods to provide read-only views of various collection types, such as `unmodifiableSet()`, `unmodifiableList()`, etc.  For these view objects, the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods forward calls to the underlying collection... With one odd exception: `unmodifiableCollection()`.

The JavaDoc [explicitly states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableCollection%28java.util.Collection%29):

> The returned collection does *not* pass the hashCode and equals operations through to the backing collection, but relies on `Object`'s `equals` and `hashCode` methods. This is necessary to preserve the contracts of these operations in the case that the backing collection is a set or a list.

My question: wtf is this talking about?? If the backing collection is a set or a list, I'd expect behavior consistent with `unmodifiableSet()` and `unmodifiableList()`.  How would that violate the hashCode/equals contracts?

Answer (score 16):

From the JavaDoc for Collection:

> The general contract for the Object.equals method states that equals
>   must be symmetric (in other words, a.equals(b) if and only if
>   b.equals(a)). The contracts for List.equals and Set.equals state that
>   lists are only equal to other lists, and sets to other sets. Thus, a
>   custom equals method for a collection class that implements neither
>   the List nor Set interface must return false when this collection is
>   compared to any list or set. (By the same logic, it is not possible to
>   write a class that correctly implements both the Set and List
>   interfaces.)

An `UnmodifiableList` is an `UnmodifiableCollection`, but the same is not true in reverse -- an `UnmodifiableCollection` that wraps a `List` is *not* an `UnmodifiableList`.  So if you compare an `UnmodifiableCollection` that wraps a List `a` with an `UnmodifiableList` that wraps the same List `a`, the two wrappers should not be equal.  If you just passed through to the wrapped list, they would be equal.

Comment: One thought is that UnmodifiableCollection could check the type of the other -- if it's a Collection but not a List or a Set, I don't see the harm in allowing comparison. That would allow UnmodifiableCollection to have a working comparison against other UnmodifiableCollections plus some other cases. Mysteriously failing the comparison is a nasty corner-case trap & this would make the "corner" rather a lot smaller, while still preserving symmetry.