# Unmodifiable collection equality in Java

Tags: java, collections, equals

Why does the following test fail in Java?

```
@Test
public void testUnmodifiableCollection() {
    Collection<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    strList.add("foo1");
    strList.add("foo2");
    Collection<String> col1 = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(strList);
    Collection<String> col2 = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(strList);
    Assert.assertTrue(col1.equals(col2));
}
```

Comment: _The returned collection does not pass the `hashCode` and `equals` operations through to the backing collection, but relies on Object's `equals` and `hashCode` methods. **This is necessary to preserve the contracts of these operations in the case that the backing collection is a set or a list**._

Comment: Why on Earth did someone downvote this question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the call to `Collections.unmodifiableCollection(Collection)` returns an `UnmodifiableCollection`, which does not implement its own `equals` method and only implements the `Collection` interface. Therefore, `Object.equals(Object)` is used which compares the object references with one another. Since you are comparing two different references, the result is false.

The fact that `equals` (and `hashCode`) are not passed to the underlying collection is also documented in the Javadoc:

> The returned collection does *not* pass the hashCode and equals
>   operations through to the backing collection, but relies on `Object`'s
>   `equals` and `hashCode` methods. This is necessary to preserve the
>   contracts of these operations in the case that the backing collection
>   is a set or a list.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12851469/3790806) for a good explanation why anything else would violate the contracts of `List`s and `Set`s.

Comment: For the above code snippet, if I use Assert.assertEquals(col1, col2); , the test passes? Why is that? Are the references same for objects col1 and col2?

Comment: It's because col1.toString() is compared to col2.toString()?

Comment: `Assert.assertEquals(col1, col2)` is exactly the same as `Assert.assertTrue(col1.equals(col2))` and will also fail.